# PHP foreach loop through multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
$arr_nav = array( array( "id" => "apple", 
          "url" => "apple.html",
          "name" => "My Apple" 
        ),
        array( "id" => "orange", 
          "url" => "orange/oranges.html",
          "name" => "View All Oranges",
        ),
        array( "id" => "pear", 
          "url" => "pear.html",
          "name" => "A Pear"
        )       
 );
```

Which I would like to use a foreach loop to replace (which only allows me to set the number:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row++)
```

with the ability to display a `.first` and `.last` class for the relevant array values

**Edit**

I would like the data to be echoed as:

```
<li id="' . $arr_nav[$row]["id"] . '"><a href="' . $v_url_root . $arr_nav[$row]["url"] . '" title="' . $arr_nav[$row]["name"] . '">"' . $arr_nav[$row]["name"] . '</a></li>' . "\r\n";
```

Many thanks for your quick responses. StackOverflow rocks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
$last = count($arr_nav) - 1;

foreach ($arr_nav as $i => $row)
{
    $isFirst = ($i == 0);
    $isLast = ($i == $last);

    echo ... $row['name'] ... $row['url'] ...;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks!

I used:
(($isLast) ? ' class="last-child"' : '')

to add a class to the list-item

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$php_multi_array = array("lang"=>"PHP", "type"=>array("c_type"=>"MULTI", "p_type"=>"ARRAY"));

//Iterate through an array declared above

foreach($php_multi_array as $key => $value)
{
    if (!is_array($value))
    {
        echo $key ." => ". $value ."\r\n" ;
    }
    else
    {
       echo $key ." => array( \r\n";

       foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2)
       {
           echo "\t". $key2 ." => ". $value2 ."\r\n";
       }

       echo ")";
    }
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
lang => PHP
type => array( 
    c_type => MULTI
    p_type => ARRAY
)
```

Comment: only 1 level..we need more multi dimensional

Comment: @aswzen you can use recursion like this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006609/php-recursion-print-all-elements-of-a-multidimensional-array-with-keys#answer-14006639

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the first and last entry of the array when talking about a.first and a.last, it goes like this:

```
foreach ($arr_nav as $inner_array) {
    echo reset($inner_array); //apple, orange, pear
    echo end($inner_array); //My Apple, View All Oranges, A Pear
}
```

arrays in PHP have an internal pointer which you can manipulate with [reset](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php), [next](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php), [end](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php). Retrieving keys/values works with [key](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) and [current](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php), but using [each](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) might be better in many cases..

Comment: Apologies for being a little unclear. I would like the values to be shown as:

<li id="' . $arr_nav[$row]["id"] . '"><a href="' . $v_url_root . $arr_nav[$row]["url"] . '" title="' . $arr_nav[$row]["name"] . '">' . $arr_nav[$row]["name"] . '</a></li>' . "\r\n";

with a check each loop - to add a class to the 'li'

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. lot of creativity.!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$first = reset($arr_nav); // Get the first element
$last  = end($arr_nav);   // Get the last element
// Ensure that we have a first element and that it's an array
if(is_array($first)) { 
   $first['class'] = 'first';
}
// Ensure we have a last element and that it differs from the first
if(is_array($last) && $last !== $first) {
   $last['class'] = 'last';
}
```

Now you could just echo the class inside you html-generator. Would probably need some kind of check to ensure that the class is set, or provide a default empty class to the array.