# Accessing Arrays inside Arrays In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

Hello I want to access inactive tags inside this array any idea?

```
stdClass::__set_state(
array
  'languages' => 
    array
      76 => 
        array
          'id' => string '76' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'Deutsch' (length=7)
  'targets' => 
    array
      81 => 
        array
          'id' => string '81' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'Deutschland' (length=11)
  'tags' => 
    array
      7866 => 
        array
          'id' => string '7866' (length=4)
          'tag' => string 'automobile' (length=10)
      17800 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17800' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'seat leon' (length=9)
      17801 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17801' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'seat leon cupra' (length=15)
  'inactiveTags' => 
    array
      195 => 
        array
          'id' => string '195' (length=3)
          'tag' => string 'auto' (length=4)
      17804 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17804' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'coupès' (length=6)
      17805 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17805' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'fahrdynamik' (length=11)
      901 => 
        array
          'id' => string '901' (length=3)
          'tag' => string 'fahrzeuge' (length=9)
      17802 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17802' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'günstige neuwagen' (length=17)
      1991 => 
        array
          'id' => string '1991' (length=4)
          'tag' => string 'motorsport' (length=10)
      2154 => 
        array
          'id' => string '2154' (length=4)
          'tag' => string 'neuwagen' (length=8)
      10660 => 
        array
          'id' => string '10660' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'seat' (length=4)
      17803 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17803' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'sportliche ausstrahlung' (length=23)
      74 => 
        array
          'id' => string '74' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'web 2.0' (length=7)
  'categories' => 
    array
      16082 => 
        array
          'id' => string '16082' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'Auto & Motorrad' (length=15)
      51 => 
        array
          'id' => string '51' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'Blogosphäre' (length=11)
      66 => 
        array
          'id' => string '66' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'Neues & Trends' (length=14)
      68 => 
        array
          'id' => string '68' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'Privat' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can access the inactive tags array with (assuming $myArray contains the array)

```
$myArray['inactiveTags'];
```

Your question doesn't seem to go beyond accessing the contents of the inactiveTags key so I can only speculate with what your final goal is.

The first key:value pair in the inactiveTags array is

```
array ('195' => array(
                 'id' => 195, 
                 'tag' => 'auto')
      )
```

To access the tag value, you would use

```
$myArray['inactiveTags'][195]['tag']; // auto
```

If you want to loop through each inactiveTags element, I would suggest:

```
foreach($myArray['inactiveTags'] as $value) {
  print $value['id'];
  print $value['tag'];
}
```

This will print all the id and tag values for each inactiveTag

Edit:: For others to see, here is a var_dump of the array provided in the question since it has not readible

```
array
  'languages' => 
    array
      76 => 
        array
          'id' => string '76' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'Deutsch' (length=7)
  'targets' => 
    array
      81 => 
        array
          'id' => string '81' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'Deutschland' (length=11)
  'tags' => 
    array
      7866 => 
        array
          'id' => string '7866' (length=4)
          'tag' => string 'automobile' (length=10)
      17800 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17800' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'seat leon' (length=9)
      17801 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17801' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'seat leon cupra' (length=15)
  'inactiveTags' => 
    array
      195 => 
        array
          'id' => string '195' (length=3)
          'tag' => string 'auto' (length=4)
      17804 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17804' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'coupès' (length=6)
      17805 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17805' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'fahrdynamik' (length=11)
      901 => 
        array
          'id' => string '901' (length=3)
          'tag' => string 'fahrzeuge' (length=9)
      17802 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17802' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'günstige neuwagen' (length=17)
      1991 => 
        array
          'id' => string '1991' (length=4)
          'tag' => string 'motorsport' (length=10)
      2154 => 
        array
          'id' => string '2154' (length=4)
          'tag' => string 'neuwagen' (length=8)
      10660 => 
        array
          'id' => string '10660' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'seat' (length=4)
      17803 => 
        array
          'id' => string '17803' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'sportliche ausstrahlung' (length=23)
      74 => 
        array
          'id' => string '74' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'web 2.0' (length=7)
  'categories' => 
    array
      16082 => 
        array
          'id' => string '16082' (length=5)
          'tag' => string 'Auto & Motorrad' (length=15)
      51 => 
        array
          'id' => string '51' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'Blogosphäre' (length=11)
      66 => 
        array
          'id' => string '66' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'Neues & Trends' (length=14)
      68 => 
        array
          'id' => string '68' (length=2)
          'tag' => string 'Privat' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$a` is the array that's passed, `$a[76][0]['id']` should give '76' and `$a[76][1]['id']` should give '81', but I can't test as I don't have PHP installed on this machine.

Comment: sorry but that makes it much more complicatet

Comment: Shouldn't `['languages']` be in there somewhere?

Comment: There is one 'Deutsch' is the language

Comment: The array in the question is very poorly formatted and hard to read. The 76 key is within the 'languages' array.  The inactiveTags is a parent key with its own set of nested arrays. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Study up on [multidimensional arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842956/php-foreach-loop-through-multidimensional-array) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your code:
It's slightly hard to read... If you want to try to view it all in a php array format, just print_r it.
This might help:

```
<?php
$a =
array(  

  'languages' =>    

  array (   

  76 =>      

 array (       'id' => '76',       'tag' => 'Deutsch',     ),   ),    'targets' =>    
 array (     81 =>      
 array (       'id' => '81',       'tag' => 'Deutschland',     ),   ),    'tags' =>    
 array (     7866 =>      
 array (       'id' => '7866',       'tag' => 'automobile',     ),     17800 =>      
 array (       'id' => '17800',       'tag' => 'seat leon',     ),     17801 =>      
 array (       'id' => '17801',       'tag' => 'seat leon cupra',     ),   ),   
'inactiveTags' =>    
 array (     195 =>      
 array (       'id' => '195',       'tag' => 'auto',     ),     17804 =>      
 array (       'id' => '17804',       'tag' => 'coupès',     ),     17805 =>      
 array (       'id' => '17805',       'tag' => 'fahrdynamik',     ),     901 =>      
 array (       'id' => '901',       'tag' => 'fahrzeuge',     ),     17802 =>      
 array (       'id' => '17802',       'tag' => 'günstige neuwagen',     ),     1991 =>      
 array (       'id' => '1991',       'tag' => 'motorsport',     ),     2154 =>      
 array (       'id' => '2154',       'tag' => 'neuwagen',     ),     10660 =>      
 array (       'id' => '10660',       'tag' => 'seat',     ),     17803 =>      
 array (       'id' => '17803',       'tag' => 'sportliche ausstrahlung',     ),     74 =>      
 array (       'id' => '74',       'tag' => 'web 2.0',     ),   ),    'categories' =>    
 array (     16082 =>      
 array (       'id' => '16082',       'tag' => 'Auto & Motorrad',     ),     51 =>      
 array (       'id' => '51',       'tag' => 'Blogosphäre',     ),     66 =>      
 array (       'id' => '66',       'tag' => 'Neues & Trends',     ),     68 =>      
 array (       'id' => '68',       'tag' => 'Privat',     ),   ), );

 printarr($a);
 printarr($a['languages'][76]['tag']);
 parintarr($a['targets'][81]['id']); 
 function printarr($in){
 echo "\n";
 print_r($in);
 echo "\n";
 }
 //run in php command line php path/to/file.php to test, switching otu the print_r.
```