# recursively - all possibilities - PHP

Tags: php

I've got an array in format:

```
$array['something_1'] = array('aother_1','aother_2',...,'aother_n')
$array['something_2'] = array('bother_1','bother_2',...,'bother_n')
...
$array['something_m'] = array('zother_1','zother_2',...,'zother_n')
```

`n,m` are variable

What I need to do is to create new table that with all sets of something with all posibilities of (x)other ...

```
$array[] = array('something_1' => 'aother_1','something_2' => 'bother_1', ..., 'something_m' => 'zother_1');
$array[] = array('something_1' => 'aother_2','something_2' => 'bother_1', ..., 'something_m' => 'zother_1');
...
$array[] = array('something_1' => 'aother_n','something_2' => 'bother_n', ..., 'something_m' => 'zother_n');
```

Basically would like to have all sets of indexes with all possibilities of values.

Some real example:

```
$input = array(
   'obj1' => array('val1','val2','val3'), 
   'obj2' => array('val4','val5')
);

$output = array(
   [] => array('obj1' => 'val1','obj2' => 'val4'),
   [] => array('obj1' => 'val2','obj2' => 'val4'),
   [] => array('obj1' => 'val3','obj2' => 'val4'),
   [] => array('obj1' => 'val1','obj2' => 'val5'),
   [] => array('obj1' => 'val2','obj2' => 'val5'),
   [] => array('obj1' => 'val3','obj2' => 'val5'),
)
```

Real cases are much bigger than this example... may contain like 1000 objects and like 20 values per object.

Normally on that example I could use double foreach ... but with 1000 objects, using 1000 foreach seems to be a bit... idiotic :D

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: What's wrong with recursion ? This might assist : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006609/php-recursion-print-all-elements-of-a-multidimensional-array-with-keys

Comment: I'm pretty bad in recursive thinking... it's really hard for me to take any tries... recursion would be neeeded, because we don't really know how many elements are there... either indexes neither values.

Comment: at least , you should draw a question with expected output..

Comment: It's easier to help you if you show some attempt (even if it's really bad attempt) so we can work upon it and show you where you've wronged.

Comment: I did edit question to add full example.

Comment: You added: "Normally on that example I could use double foreach ... but with 1000 objects, using 1000 foreach seems to be a bit... idiotic :D". I don't see how you can do this with two foreach loops if you don't know the number of n and m. I think it is more complicated, but maybe I miss some smart solution. :-)

Comment: Yes it is complicated, that was as answer for question "why recursive" in one of the comments.

Comment: I couldn't resist building it without recursive logic. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: seems fair, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that takes any combination of n and m, and doesn't use recursive logic (which you dislike).

It effectively keeps track of the number of elements in each sub-array, lowers them by one, and if they reach -1, set back to the original count.

It also uses some link-list like behaviour (terminating when the first key 'curindex' cannot be lowered.)

```
<?php
$input = array(
   'obj1' => array('val1','val2','val3'), 
   'obj2' => array('val4','val5'),
   'obj3' => array('val6','val7')
);  

// find last key
$keys = array_keys($input);
$lastKey = $keys[count($keys)-1];

// create currentindex and maxindex for each 
$CMI = array();

$former = '';
foreach ($input as $key => $valARR){
    $CMI[$key]["maxindex"] = count($valARR)-1;
    $CMI[$key]["curindex"] = count($valARR)-1;
    // linkedlist like behaviour. obj3 -> obj2 -> obj1 -> ''
    $CMI[$key]["former"] = $former;
    $former = $key;     
}

$output = array();
$bRunning = true;

while ($bRunning){
    $oneCombi = array();
    foreach ($input as $key => $valARR){
        $oneCombi[$key] = $valARR[$CMI[$key]["curindex"]];
    }
    $output[] = $oneCombi;

    // Now lower curindex of last one, all the way up to first one, then quit.
    $bLowering = true;
    $curKey = $lastKey;
    while ($bLowering){
        $CMI[$curKey]["curindex"]--;
        if ($CMI[$curKey]["curindex"] == -1){
            $CMI[$curKey]["curindex"] = $CMI[$curKey]["maxindex"];
            $curKey = $CMI[$curKey]["former"];
            if ($curKey == ''){
                // no more combinations
                $bLowering = false;
                $bRunning = false;
            }
        } else {
            $bLowering = false;
        }
    }
}

// optionally reverse to match your original example:
$output = array_reverse($output);

echo "endresult:<pre>";
var_dump($output);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```