# loop through 3-dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to loop through a multidimensional array and keep banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out.
I am essentially trying to print all values of ID.

This is what I have so far, but it keeps giving me an "array to string conversion" error.

```
foreach ($threadsarray as $key => $threads) {   
    foreach ($threads as $anotherkey => $i) {
        foreach($i as $id => $threadid)
        echo 'key:'.$key[0]. ' AnotherKey: '.$anotherkey["threads"].' AnotherAnotherKey: '.$i["id"].' value:'.$threadid.'<br>';
    }
}
```

I'm trying to mimic what this would do, but using a "For Loop"

```
$threadsarray['threads']['0']['id'];
$threadsarray['threads']['1']['id'];
```

And here is the array.....

```
Array
(
    [threads] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [archived] => 
                    [attachment] => 
                    [business_purpose] => booking_direct_thread
                    [id] => 178369845
                    [inquiry_reservation] => 
                    [last_message_at] => 2017-04-07T18:52:07Z
                    [listing] => Array
                        (
```

Comment: And what? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way it can be done

```
foreach ($threadsarray['threads'] as $thread) {   
     print $thread['id'];
}
```

`for` version

```
$idx = count($threadsarray['threads']);
for($i=0;$i<$idx;$i++){
   print $threadsarray['threads'][$i]['id'];
}
```

Comment: You don't need second `foreach`

Comment: @u_mulder Why? Should he do `echo $threads[0]['id'];`? Then he can simply take the code lines from is middle block. plz, explain.

Comment: @u_mulder yep, sry, you are right, its getting late here... thnx for hint

Comment: I like this.  How do I insert a <br> after each thread id so they all don't show up on one line?

Comment: The "for" version is giving me "Undefined offset: 10" error

Comment: @sjackson Change `$i<=$idx` to `$i<$idx`. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to echo out an Array.

I would do this:

```
foreach($threadsarray['threads'] as $key => $thread){
    echo 'key:' . $key . ' - ';
    foreach($thread as $key2 => $value2){
        echo 'key2:' . $key2 . ' - ';
        if(is_array($value2)){
            foreach($value2 as $key3 => $value3){
                echo 'key3:' . $key3 . ' - value3: ' . $value3;
            }
        }else{
            echo 'value: ' . $value2;
        }
    }
}
```

you can always inspect the whole array structure doing `print_r($threadsarray)`

Better use a recursive function for any amount of 'levels':

```
function printAll($a) {
    if (!is_array($a)) {
        echo $a, ' ';
        return;
    }

    foreach($a as $k => $value) {

         printAll($k);
         printAll($value);

    }
}
```

You can call it like: `printAll($threadsarray);`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006609/php-recursion-print-all-elements-of-a-multidimensional-array-with-keys)

Comment: This one gives me an "array to string conversion" error...  Is it because there is another nested array somewhere down the line.... ?

Comment: Then $value3 is another array, I suggest writing a recursive function that goes through every level echoing the 'key' and if the 'value' is array call itself otherwise echoes the 'value'

Comment: That's kind of what I had suspected...how do I do that?

Comment: Just edited the answer and added a recursive function to do this.

Comment: Much appreciated, but what if I don't necessarily know if $k < 10.  That number ($k) could be 2 or it could be 10 or it could be 5....

Comment: Updated answer without this example condition.

Comment: Thank you.  Very much appreciated!