# Find value in php array without some details

Tags: php

I have this array from an API:

```
array(2) {
  ["messages"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Success"
  }
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["INST4841_NNN59"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["English"]=>
      array(1) {
        [4380258]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=> 
          array(12) {
            ["idinstance"]=>
            string(8) "11059013"
            ["idassessment"]=>
            string(2) "53"
            ["assessmenttitle"]=>
            string(17) "English Screening"
            ["idlevel"]=>
            string(1) "6"
            ["level"]=>
            string(7) "Level 2"
            ["start"]=>
            string(19) "10:27:21 30-05-2017"
            ["finish"]=>
            string(19) "10:33:10 30-05-2017"
            ["timetaken"]=>
            string(3) "335"
            ["idsubject"]=>
            string(2) "10"
            ["subjecttitle"]=>
            string(7) "English"
            ["possible"]=>
            int(15)
            ["actual"]=>
            int(15)
          }
          [1]=>
          array(12) {
            ["idinstance"]=>
            string(8) "11059105"
            ["idassessment"]=>
            string(2) "49"
            ["assessmenttitle"]=>
            string(26) "English Initial Assessment"
            ["idlevel"]=>
            string(1) "4"
            ["level"]=>
            string(13) "Entry Level 3"
            ["start"]=>
            string(19) "10:33:13 30-05-2017"
            ["finish"]=>
            string(19) "10:35:03 30-05-2017"
            ["timetaken"]=>
            string(3) "421"
            ["idsubject"]=>
            string(2) "10"
            ["subjecttitle"]=>
            string(7) "English"
            ["possible"]=>
            int(22)
            ["actual"]=>
            float(8.2)
          }
          [2]=>
          array(12) {
            ["idinstance"]=>
            string(8) "11059147"
            ["idassessment"]=>
            string(2) "57"
            ["assessmenttitle"]=>
            string(18) "English Diagnostic"
            ["idlevel"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["level"]=>
            string(13) "Entry Level 2"
            ["start"]=>
            string(19) "10:35:09 30-05-2017"
            ["finish"]=>
            string(19) "10:35:44 30-05-2017"
            ["timetaken"]=>
            string(2) "20"
            ["idsubject"]=>
            string(2) "10"
            ["subjecttitle"]=>
            string(7) "English"
            ["possible"]=>
            int(67)
            ["actual"]=>
            int(5)
          }
        }
      }
      ["ICT"]=>
      array(1) {
        [4380260]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(12) {
            ["idinstance"]=>
            string(8) "11059399"
            ["idassessment"]=>
            string(4) "1185"
            ["assessmenttitle"]=>
            string(22) "ICT Initial Assessment"
            ["idlevel"]=>
            string(1) "5"
            ["level"]=>
            string(7) "Level 1"
            ["start"]=>
            string(19) "10:52:05 30-05-2017"
            ["finish"]=>
            string(19) "10:58:04 30-05-2017"
            ["timetaken"]=>
            string(3) "339"
            ["idsubject"]=>
            string(2) "12"
            ["subjecttitle"]=>
            string(3) "ICT"
            ["possible"]=>
            int(79)
            ["actual"]=>
            float(66.7)
          }
          [1]=>
          array(12) {
            ["idinstance"]=>
            string(8) "11059509"
            ["idassessment"]=>
            string(4) "1189"
            ["assessmenttitle"]=>
            string(14) "ICT Diagnostic"
            ["idlevel"]=>
            string(1) "6"
            ["level"]=>
            string(7) "Level 2"
            ["start"]=>
            string(19) "10:58:07 30-05-2017"
            ["finish"]=>
            string(19) "10:58:29 30-05-2017"
            ["timetaken"]=>
            string(2) "14"
            ["idsubject"]=>
            string(2) "12"
            ["subjecttitle"]=>
            string(3) "ICT"
            ["possible"]=>
            int(19)
            ["actual"]=>
            int(1)
          }
        }
      }
      ["Maths"]=>
      array(1) {
        [4380259]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(11) {
            ["idinstance"]=>
            string(8) "11059522"
            ["idassessment"]=>
            string(2) "52"
            ["assessmenttitle"]=>
            string(15) "Maths Screening"
            ["idlevel"]=>
            string(1) "2"
            ["level"]=>
            string(13) "Entry Level 1"
            ["start"]=>
            string(19) "10:58:45 30-05-2017"
            ["finish"]=>
            string(19) "10:58:50 30-05-2017"
            ["idsubject"]=>
            string(2) "11"
            ["subjecttitle"]=>
            string(5) "Maths"
            ["possible"]=>
            int(4)
            ["actual"]=>
            int(0)
          }
          [1]=>
          array(12) {
            ["idinstance"]=>
            string(8) "11059523"
            ["idassessment"]=>
            string(2) "48"
            ["assessmenttitle"]=>
            string(24) "Maths Initial Assessment"
            ["idlevel"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["level"]=>
            string(9) "Pre Entry"
            ["start"]=>
            string(19) "10:58:52 30-05-2017"
            ["finish"]=>
            string(19) "10:59:06 30-05-2017"
            ["timetaken"]=>
            string(1) "6"
            ["idsubject"]=>
            string(2) "11"
            ["subjecttitle"]=>
            string(5) "Maths"
            ["possible"]=>
            int(0)
            ["actual"]=>
            int(0)
          }
          [2]=>
          array(12) {
            ["idinstance"]=>
            string(8) "11059530"
            ["idassessment"]=>
            string(2) "54"
            ["assessmenttitle"]=>
            string(16) "Maths Diagnostic"
            ["idlevel"]=>
            string(1) "2"
            ["level"]=>
            string(13) "Entry Level 1"
            ["start"]=>
            string(19) "10:59:08 30-05-2017"
            ["finish"]=>
            string(19) "11:01:12 30-05-2017"
            ["timetaken"]=>
            string(2) "92"
            ["idsubject"]=>
            string(2) "11"
            ["subjecttitle"]=>
            string(5) "Maths"
            ["possible"]=>
            int(63)
            ["actual"]=>
            float(15.2)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can get the level of English Initial Assessment using:

```
$english = $json['data']['INST4841_NNN59']['English'][4380258][1]['level'];
```

However I need to run it in a loop and [4380258] and [1] vary. How can I get the level without these values?

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006609/php-recursion-print-all-elements-of-a-multidimensional-array-with-keys#answer-14006639. You just need to edit it a bit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($json['data']['INST4841_NNN59']['English'] as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        if (isset($v['assessmenttitle']) 
            &&
            $v['assessmenttitle'] == 'English Initial Assessment'
            &&
            isset($v['level'])
        ) {
            echo $v['level'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't downvote. This outputs all three levels, ie "Level 2Entry Level 3Entry Level 2" the API may return one, two or three of these. I need specifically the English Initial Assessment one?

Comment: Thanks very much works perfectly, I have tried to upvote but I don't have enough reputation. I will as soon as I do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive method:

```
function loop_array($array = [], $return = []) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $return = loop_array($array[$key], $return);
        }
        elseif ($key === 'level') {
                $return[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

$information = [
    'subinformation' => [
        'another_level' => [
            'level' => 'new level'
        ]
    ],
    'level' => 1,
    'another_sublevel_thing' => [
        'new_sublevel' => [
            'level' => 'first'
        ]
    ]
];

$levels = loop_array($information);
```

This will generate the following array:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "new level"
    [1]=>
    int(1)
    [2]=>
    string(5) "first"
}
```