# How to access elements inside MultiDimensional Array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How to access all the elements under each key of multidimensional array.

```
$multi = array
(
    "Abhishek" => array("Choudhary", "Bunta", "Popy"),
    "Bond"     => array("One", "two", "three", "four"),
    "Super"    => array("T1", "T2")
);


$data = array("Abhishek","Bond","Super");           

for($j = 0;$j<count($data);$j++)
{
    echo "<br/>Main Array Value ".$data[$j]."<br/>";

    for($i = 0;$i<count($data[$j]);$i++)
    {
        echo "sub Value ".$multi[$data[$j]][$i]." count ".count($data[$j]) ;
    }
}
```

Now I want to iterate through each element of Abhishek , Bond and Super , so we can see Abhishek has 3 elements inside it but $data[$j] always return 1. If I increment then I can access Bunta 
Currently the output is -

```
Main Array Value Abhishek
sub Value Bunta
Main Array Value Bond
sub Value two
Main Array Value Super
sub Value T2
```

**and expected is:**

**

```
Main Array Value Abhishek
 sub Value choudhary
 sub Value Bunta
 sub Value Popy
:
:
Main Array Value Bond
 sub Value two
Main Array Value Super
 sub Value T2
```

**

**Disclaimer** : I am super new to PHP so may be my expectation can be invalid or I am missing some very silly thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i recommend you read some articles about [multidim](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) arrays, anyway your needs could be done with following code:

```
foreach($multi as $key => $value) {
    echo "<br/>Main Array Value ".$key."<br/>";
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($value); $i++) {
        echo "sub Value ".$value[$i]." count ".sizeof($value) ;
    }
}
```

PS: you don't need `$data` array

Answer (score 2):

@bunta please check this out: [PHP Foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

You could use foreach instead.

Also:

[PHP foreach loop through multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842956/php-foreach-loop-through-multidimensional-array)

HTH.

Comment: This supposed to be a comment since it's not giving clear answer to the question

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Thanks, I forgot to add the link to the answer.

Comment: Link-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Using `foreach()` would be easier

```
foreach ($multi as $key => $subarray)
{
    echo $key . '<br />';

    foreach ($subarray as $subvalue)
    {
        echo ' - '.$subvalue . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Will output

```
Abhishek
- Choudhary
- Bunta
- Popy
Bond
- One
- two
- three
- four
Super
- T1
- T2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php

foreach($multi as $key => $value) {
    echo "<br/>Parent Value ".$key."<br/>";
    for($i = 0; $ < sizeof($value); $++) {
        echo "Child Value ".$value[$i]." count ".sizeof($value) ;
    }
}

?>

You are using wrong syntax to access it.
```

- Thanks

Answer (score -1):

All you need is use foreach to iterate on $multi array (if you just want to know the number of subelements for each element level 1):

```
 <?php
echo "<br\>multiDimensional Array<br\>";
$multi = array("Abhishek" =>array
                        ("Choudhary",
                            "Bunta",
                            "Popy"),
               "Bond" => array
                           ("One",
                               "two",
                               "three",
                               "four"),
               "Super" => array
                           ("T1",
                               "T2")
);


foreach( $multi as $value ){
    echo " count ".count($value) ;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I give a way to iterate and I precised that it was useful if one would wants to know the number of subelements.