# Loop Multidimensional PHP arrays and display all the corresponding array

Tags: php, associative-array

I've found an almost similar problem on this topic [Loop Multidimensional PHP arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837638/loop-multidimensional-php-arrays)
My array is a little different but almost similar:

```php
Array  
    (   
        [size] => int (995)
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [service] => 8000
                        [network] => xxx.xxx.xxx
                    )
            
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [service] => 9000
                        [network] => xxx.xxx.xxx
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [service] => 9500
                        [network] => xxx.xxx.xxx
                    )
            )    
    )
```

I d like to check all the `service` values in order to see if the number entered by the user is valid and exists, and display the corresponding `network`

Here is my naïve try:

```
$record = NULL;

// let's assume $x as this array here
foreach($record in $x['data']){
    if($record['service'] == $bus){
        break;
    }
}

if($record){
    // record found
    var_dump($record);
}else{
    echo "Not found";
}
```

Comment: Before using `foreach` loop, you should check the doc https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick. I just Don't understand why in the link I posted, he needs tto use 3 imbricated foreach loop and I need to use only one ?

Comment: In the question you posted the user wanted to print all the items, subitems and subsubitems. In your case you need to iterate over only one level `$x['data']` and print an item if it fits.

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: Of course not but I don't understand why I had a negative vote on my post. I really took time to write it most clear as possible

Comment: I don't know why either. I was just trying to see if an answer helped you then mark it Accepted or if you have issues or other questions post them.

Comment: He just forgot to mark my answer. Lol @AbraCadaver (since he said he solved his problem through my suggestions in the comments, I suppose). I don't mind if they marked it or not but that would help someone who has a similar issue with less of a hassle going through all the answers.

Comment: No it's just that i can't mark any comment as I have a ban on my profile  and I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, assuming that `service` is unique:

```
$services = array_column($x['data'], null, 'service');

if(isset($services[$bus]) {
    echo $services[$bus]['network'];
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

- Extract an array and index it by `service`
- Now you can access it by `$services[$bus]` ex. `$services[8000]['network']`.

Answer (score 0):

almost right :

forEach syntax is the other way round : `forEach(<array> as $iterator)`
 oh an you need to handle the assignment to the $reslt variable (which I renamed to $found for some reason ) a bit different

```
 $found=NULL;
    // let's assume $x as this array here
    foreach($x['data'] as $record ){
        if($record['service'] == $bus){
            $found=$record['service'];
        }
    }

    if($found != NULL){
        // record found
        var_dump($record);
    }else{
        echo "Not found";
    }
```

Comment: Please add here some description of what have you changed in the code or where the mistake was.

Comment: He changed the statement "in" to "as" in the foreach parameters, and added a var_dump($record); line in the if statement bellow.

Comment: Ok, but still please add some description to the post remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your question right, it should be something like this:

```
// For the sake of the example, first I reconstructed your array:
$ar1 = array("service" => 8000, "network" => "111.111.111");
$ar2 = array("service" => 9000, "network" => "222.222.222");
$ar3 = array("service" => 9500, "network" => "333.333.333");
$x = array("size" => 995,
        "data" => array($ar1,$ar2,$ar3));

$record = NULL;
$bus = 9000;

for($n = 0; $n < count($x["data"]); $n++){
    $checkService = $x["data"][$n];
    if($checkService["service"] == $bus){
        $record = $checkService["network"];
    }
}

if ($record) {
    // If record found:
    echo "Lookup Results for ".$bus.": ".$record;
    // Since we are searching for 9000 in this example, this should output -> Lookup Results for 9000: 222.222.222
} else {
    echo "Record not found";
}
```

This code could be simplified even further but I'm not sure what you need exactly.

You can check the end result through [this example](https://3v4l.org/BYDSj).

Comment: Thanks a lot Markafa, you are the only one who understood what I needed! Many thanks !

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. Did it help you solve your problem though? Or do you need further explanation/assistance with your problem? @john_johnk

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Johnathon Heindl:(sorry i cannot reply yet).

It may be useful to make $found an array, in case you found the same service having different networks.

```
$found=[];
// let's assume $x as this array here
foreach($x['data'] as $record ){
   if($record['service'] == $bus){
       //appends to $found
       $found[]=$record['service'];
   }
}
if(!empty($found){
   // record(s) found
   var_dump($record);
}else{
   echo "Not found";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$found_record = NULL;
// let's assume $x as this array here
foreach($record in $x['data']){
if($record['service'] == $bus){
     $found_record = $record['service'];
      break;
    }
  }
 if($found_record){
   // record found
   var_dump($record);
  }else{
    echo "Not found";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.